# How do I properly access file system files via .net Web API?

Tags: .net, webapi

I have a shared dll that has an app config setting to reference a location of an html body.  The service takes variables and replaces strings inside the html body.

The dll references the file via ConfigurationManager like so:

```
File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HtmlBodyLocation"]);
```

My app settings are as such:

```
<add key="HtmlBodyLocation" value="Services/Assets/HtmlEmail.html" />
```

When I use this dll via a WebAPI project, I get errors that the file cannot be found (currently the error is such as I'm still testing it via IIS Express):

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Services\Assets\HtmlEmail.html'

How do I configure the app settings on my API server to be able to access this file?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value retrieved by your config to [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx)

```
string location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HtmlBodyLocation"])
var data = File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(location));
```

This will map the partial path relative to the root of your webapi app to the physical path on the target machine

Also you probably need to change the path stored in your config to

```
<add key="HtmlBodyLocation" value="~/Services/Assets/HtmlEmail.html" />
```

Comment: the library is mainly used by console apps so I'm not sure I can get them to  use a Web.Hosting library nor am not sure it would work.  Do I need to think about using something else?